# how to fetch particular method from a json responseString in webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, json

I have a text field and button and a webview below.

When I enter the string in a text field and press search button, the entire JSON response string is displaying in `UIWebview` instance.

So  my requirement is to display a particular method that matches the string entered in the textfield.

even though i am entering any string in textfield when i press search button its displaying all contents in webview.

is it possible to fetch particular  method from responseString ?

Suggest changes that need to be done.

**.h file**

```
    IBOutlet UITextField *searchtextField;

    UIWebView *webView;
}

-(IBAction)search;

@property (nonatomic, retain)  UIWebView *webView;
```

**.m file**

```
-(IBAction)search
{
    NSString *searchString=searchtextField.text;    

    NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising",searchString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Comment: where are u adding searchString in urlAddress in this code     NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising",searchString];

Comment: there is no any %@ format in urlAddress stringWithFormat by whuch you can add searchString

Comment: ya the url is api and output format is in JSon..so wat change i shd make in the code ?

Comment: I say what is the use of searchString in this code as you are not using searchString anywhere in this code

Comment: ex NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=%@",searchString]

Answer (score 0):

Just Place `%@` in place of `searchString` where you want to add...This is all about from your end because I dont know where you want to add

**Example**

```
NSString *searchString=searchtextField.text;    

NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=%@",searchString];
```

Try It out....

Comment: for example this is google api..https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyDzl0Ozijg2C47iYfKgBWWkAbZE_wCJ-2U&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures so i am not getting exactly where i can place

Comment: this is from ur end where you want to put searchString

Comment: stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@ this works for google.. but if i place particular url of json responsestring it wont..

Comment: wt u want to do plz make clear and tell me after getting searchString and make clear that where you want to add searchString

Comment: from this http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json you will get search.json file

Comment: ya tat is json file....from json file i want to retrive a particular method which i enter in a search field instead of displaying whole json file..i hope u got my point...so i will enter a string in textfield i wan to search tat paticular keyword from json file and display it contents in webview...

Comment: is it possible to retrive particular method from a json file by entering a keyword in search fleld?

Comment: @Marvin  
in the above link in tat code wat i have done is..when i click just button the values ill be displayed in label...wat i wan is i need to enter string in textfield then retrieve tat data i think u got my point..

Comment: @Mehul ya i have done..u can check this link where i posted tat code...  stackoverflow.com/questions/6421690/   suggest me wat changes i shd make.